# view placed differently on iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

i have built an app that allows the user to take their picture with a selection of glasses overlaid. it is working exactly how i want it on both an ipad and ipad mini but on the iphone the position in relation the the scroll view is wrong (see Images).

```
func setupPages(){
    pageImages = [
        UIImage(named: "glasses_one")!,
        UIImage(named: "glasses_two")!,
        UIImage(named: "glasses_three")!,
        UIImage(named: "glasses_four")!,
        UIImage(named: "glasses_five")!,
        UIImage(named: "glasses_six")!
    ]

    let pageCount = pageImages.count

    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }
    print(pageViews.count)

    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:  scrollWidth * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
        height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    loadVisiblePages()
}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width

    page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))
    print(page)
    pageControl.currentPage = page

    for index in 0...5 {
        //print(" -- Index = \(index)")
        loadPage(index)
    }
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // 1
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        print(pageView.description)
        // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
    } else {
        // 2
        var frame = scrollView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = scrollWidth * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0
        frame.size.width = scrollWidth
        // 3
        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        newPageView.clipsToBounds = false
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)


        // 4
        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}
```

**Ipad**

[image]

**Iphone**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is you need to add a constraint to center you image vertically. Or you could also solve this by making the frame for your "glasses frame" A set width and height. Smaller screens will have less space around it but will still be in the middle.

Comment: Do you mean vertically? i have "fixed" it temporarily by making the scrollview a bigger height.

Comment: I no longer have my iphone test device so i will get back to you on this one.